# Unable to parse list of strings in xmlhttpresponse text in ASP.NET Ajax call

Tags: asp.net, xmlhttprequest

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       alert('hi');
       var form = document.getElementById('form1');
       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr.open('GET', "Load.aspx", false);
       xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
           if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200 && xhr.responseText) {
               alert('url(' + xhr.responseText + ')');

           } else {
           }
       };

       xhr.send(null);
   });
</script>
```

Inside Load.aspx the following code sends a list of strings as response.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {        
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Write( new List<string>() { "../Temp/UP_zone.jpg", "../Temp/DP_zone.jpg" });
    Response.End();
}
```

I am unable to parse the list of string passed. The alert is showing up with content as system.generic.list.

Answer (score 0):

you need to serialize the list before response.write.
here i am using JavaScriptSerializer to serialize.

```
 List<string> lst = new List<string>() { "../Temp/UP_zone.jpg", "../Temp/DP_zone.jpg" };
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string converted = serializer.Serialize(lst);
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Write(converted);
            Response.End();
```

this will return the json as ["../Temp/UP_zone.jpg","../Temp/DP_zone.jpg"]